# Electron handle console.log messages in main process

Tags: electron, console.log

Is there way to handle console.log messages from renderer in main process? Similar to CefDisplayHandler::OnConsoleMessage handler in Cef.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in three ways,

- Set the enviroment variable`ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=true` to parse every console.log to your CLI
- Do a IPCrenderer message to IPCmain, which the logs it for you
- Add a function to app from the main process

  ```
  # MAIN
  const {app} = require('electron')
  app.MySuperCoolLoggingUtility = function (msg) { 
      console.log(msg) 
  }

  # RENDERER
  require('electron').remote.app.MySuperCoolLoggingUtility('hi')
  ```

There are also some ways to limit the log level for specific files via `--vmodule=` but it is not close to the handler of normal Cef. So you will probably build your own utility function for it.

Comment: Woha, didn't know about `ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING`. I don't know why I always forget or don't think of going through documentation more thoroughly, so that I know these things from the source, instead of discovering them on the Internet. Nevertheless, upvoted your answer, thank you! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The ability to intercept console messages generated by the renderer process, in the main process, was implemented in Electron [version `v1.8.2-beta.3`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v1.8.2-beta.3/docs/api/web-contents.md#event-console-message) (as far as I were able to determine).

To be able to handle these messages, one attaches a "console-message" event handler to the [`webContents` object property of a `BrowserWindow` object](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents).

A rather straightforward replication of messages by the main process, could be implemented as follows (`win` refers to a `BrowserWindow` you want to capture messages for):

```js
const log_level_names = { "-1": "DEBUG", "0": "INFO", "1": "WARN", "2": "ERROR" };
win.webContents.on("console-message", (ev, level, message, line, file) => {
    console.log(`${new Date().toUTCString()}\t${log_level_names[level]}\t${message} (${file}:${line})`);
});
```

Comment: `console.error(new Error('foo'))` from the web page gets sent across as just err.toString() instead of err.stack, right?